# How to write french accents to a file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

I am working under the latest version of Node.js.
I am trying to write a string I build using constants, into a text file. However, this string contains accents that I want in the text file.
Here is an example:

```
const fs = require('fs'); // to read and write files

const labels = {
    partOne: 'blàblàblé',
    partTwo: 'blîblùblàblöx'
};

let stringo = labels.partOne + labels.partTwo;

// write stringo to a specific file
const filePath = `./licence${beatName}.txt`;
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, stringo, 'utf8', err => {});
```

Unfortunately, the accents are replaced with undesirable values. For example:

- **è** becomes *Â¨s*
- **é** becomes *Â©*

I tried to encode my javascript file into UTF-8, didn't work.
How can I encode my strings into something usable for my purpose ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"é" and "Â©" are correlated:

- ["é" is encoded as](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+00E9) bytes `0xC3` `0xA9` in UTF-8
- `0xC3` `0xA9` are equal to "Â" "©" if [interpreted as ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (and other variants of ISO-8859, I suppose).

With encoding problems, it's often unclear which program is right and which is wrong, because everything you see is an interpretation of the underlying bytes.

The source file could be correctly encoded as UTF8, then the output file should also be UTF8, since Node.js expects source files and the contained string literals to be encoded as UTF-8, and `fs.writeFileSync()` is not instructed to convert to another encoding. If that's the case, the tool you use to verify the output file possibly interprets the file as ISO-8859-1.

Either you open the JavaScript source **and** the output file with an editor that can load files with an explicit encoding (I'm familiar with Visual Studio Code, command "Change File Encoding" from Command palette, then "Reopen with Encoding" (*not* Save with Encoding, which you can use for a conversion if you found the error). The currently used encoding is displayed at the status bar at the bottom.

Or open both files with a hex editor and check the bytes of the faulty letters.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it. Here is my code:

**File:** app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const routes = require('./routes');

const server = http.createServer(routes.requestListener);
server.listen(3000);
```

**File:** routes.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {parse} = require('querystring');

const requestListener = (request, response) => {
    const url = request.url;
    const method = request.method;

    if (url === '/' && method === 'GET') {
        const bodyContentCallBack = () => {
            response.write('<form action="/message" method="post">');
            response.write('<input type="text" name="message" autofocus><br/><br />');
            response.write('<button type="submit">Send</button>');
            response.write('</form>');
        };
        createHtmlPage(response, 'Message Recorder', bodyContentCallBack);
    }

    if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
        const savingFileCallBackAsync = (result) => {
            const dateTimeStamp = getDateTimeStamp();
            fs.writeFile(`message_${dateTimeStamp}.txt`, result.message, {encoding: 'utf8'}, error => {
                response.statusCode = 302;
                response.setHeader('Location', '/');
                return response.end();
            });
        }
        collectPostRequestData(request, savingFileCallBackAsync);
    }
}

const createHtmlPage = (response, pageTitle, bodyContentCallBack) => {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    response.write(`<html lang="en">`);
    response.write(`<head><title>${pageTitle}</title></head>`);
    response.write(`<body>`);
    bodyContentCallBack();
    response.write(`</body>`);
    response.write(`</html>`);
    return response.end();
}

function collectPostRequestData(request, callback) {
    const FORM_URLENCODED = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    if (request.headers['content-type'] === FORM_URLENCODED) {
        let body = '';
        request.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
        request.on('end', () => {
            callback(parse(body));
        });
    } else {
        callback(null);
    }
}

const getDateTimeStamp = () => {
    let date_ob = new Date();

    // current day
    // adjust 0 before single digit date
    let day = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);

    // current month
    let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    // current year
    let year = date_ob.getFullYear();

    // current hours
    let hours = date_ob.getHours();

    // current minutes
    let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();

    // current seconds
    let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds();

    return `${year}${month}${day}${hours}${minutes}${seconds}`;
}

exports.requestListener = requestListener;
```

**Execution: (on your terminal)**

```
node app.js
```

This will create this super-duper simple form at localhost:3000:

[image]

After typing a sentence/phrase with accented characters (hispanic letters with accents and french letters too) and clicking in the "*Send*" button, then such sentence will be saved onto .txt files

[image]

Your welcome.